# Send Ajax data to PHP

Tags: php, jquery, location

I have the following jQuery code on my page:

```
function ajaxFunction() {
$.ajax({
  url:'location.php',
  type:'POST',
  data:'lat='+lat+'&long='+long,
  success:function(d){
    console.log(d);
  },
  error(w,t,f){
    console.log(w+' '+t+' '+f);
  }
});
}
```

Now what should I put in the location.php to make the data go to my email box? I'm a total noob and looking up codes or tutorials won't work because I don't understand it...

Also can I just let the page redirect to another page if the Script is done?
Can I just add:

```
window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
```

Or should I put more code... I found all these coeds on the internet because I don't understand anything, so could you please help me?

Comment: You really need to learn how to do some stuff on your own instead of asking for really **everything** here.

Comment: Well you can just help me and then I'm gone...

Comment: *Give a man a fish and you feed him for a day. Teach a man how to fish and you feed him for a lifetime.*

Comment: I'm not a man yet... And I thought this was a site to help people...

Comment: @AlexanderSterk: yes it is, but you need to put some effort into it. Show what you tried. You're not the first person to try and email stuff via PHP, there's tons of resources out there. SO isn't a place to go to get code written for you.

Comment: If even tutorials are too hard to understand, you're probably trying too advanced stuff for your current skill level. Drop down to simpler stuff and come back to this when you have the basic skills covered.

Comment: @AlexanderSterk: That's not really related to your question, but if you start with JavaScript and PHP now, especially when googling for all kinds of stuff, you are likely to learn some extremely bad programming habits since tons of PHP/JS tutorials on the web are ancient or just bad (w3schools for example). So I'd suggest you to **stay away** from those two languages at the beginning and learn e.g. Python instead. There's a really nice tutorial called ["learn python the hard way"](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/).

Answer (score 1):

In your location.php, you could do something like this to make the data received by php script to go to your email box:

```
$messageBody = "lat: " . $_POST['lat'] . " long: " . $_POST['long'];
if (mail("youremail@domain.com", "The Subject Line", $messageBody)) {
    echo "success";
    exit;
}
```

Check out the link for more info on mail() function:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

To redirect:

```
function ajaxFunction(lat, long) {
$.ajax({
  url:'location.php',
  type:'POST',
  data:'lat='+lat+'&long='+long,
  success:function(d){
    // When the ajax call is successful, the redirection should happen here
    window.location = "http://stackoverflow.com";
  },
  error(w,t,f){
    // this is when the ajax call fails
    console.log(w+' '+t+' '+f);
  }
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`mail()`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function in PHP to send an email.
You also need to fix your JS code - unless you actually made `lat` and `long` global variables they'll be undefined.

Comment: Ok thank you, I know I should do research first but to me it's just weird codes, if you say global variables I don't understand it... I don't want you to be more kid-friendly or something, I just want you to understand that this is hard for me...